# commit in solr 4.0 takes longer time compared to solr 3.6

Tags: solr

I have recently migrated from solr 3.6 to solr 4.0. The documents in my core are getting constantly updated and so I fire a code commit after every 10 thousand docs . However moving from 3.6 to 4.0 I have noticed that for the same core size it takes about twice the time to commit in solr4.0 compared to solr 3.6.

Is there any workaround by which I can reduce this time. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Solr 4 has transaction logging enabled by default. If you don't need that, you can disable this option. I would provide a link, but the Solr Wiki is currently down for maintenance.

Comment: Here is an alternate link - http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig Jump down to the Transaction Log section at the bottom.

Comment: I am using solr 4.2 and from solr 4.2 you cannot disable transaction logs